# How do databases implement skipping?

Tags: database, algorithm, b-tree

I'm writing my own little database engine. Is there any efficient way to implement skipping function other than inspecting every leaf nodes of B+tree, which will be slow with large entries.

Comment: What do you mean by skipping?

Comment: Like `offset` in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a B+tree for your indices, all the values are stored in leaves and thus can be linked together to form an (ordered) linked list, or rather an [unrolled linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list). That's the main advantage of B+ tree over plain B trees.

That said, even if unrolled lists let you do some form of skipping, nothing prevents you from implementing [skip lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) on your records, and using the the nodes of these lists as your btree values.

Answer (score 0):

2 years after, but anyway.
You can do it in Cassandra's way too. No limit, but you specify the last key from previous query, e.g.

select * from abc where key > 123 limit 100

where 123 is last key from previous query